# influxdb : how do I filter by a field > than 4

Tags: filter, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have the following query which shows all records:

```
SELECT "ApparentPower" FROM "machine01" WHERE "pin_no" = 'pin 2 ' AND $timeFilter;
```

I want to filter by field "ApparentPower" and only show values greater than 10.   How do i do this?

If i run the query `SELECT "ApparentPower" FROM "machine01" WHERE "pin_no" = 'pin 2 ' AND $timeFilter AND "ApparentPower" > 10;`  i get no values returned even though there are values greater than 10.

Also if i run the query `SELECT "ApparentPower" FROM "machine01" WHERE "pin_no" = 'pin 2 ' AND $timeFilter AND "ApparentPower" < 10;` i get no values returned again.

However if i run the query `SELECT "ApparentPower" FROM "machine01" WHERE "pin_no" = 'pin 2 ' AND $timeFilter AND "ApparentPower" != 10;` i get all values returned.

I've checked the version of influx im running using the command  `curl -sL -I localhost:8086/ping`:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: f4132538-7129-11eb-b770-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.1.1
Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 14:10:56 GMT
```

Comment: What is the data type of the "ApparentPower" field? (SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "machine01")

Comment: weirdly they are all string, how do i correct this? I'm guessing they want to be integer? 

pin_no string
ApparentPower string
AnalogueRead string

Comment: i cant edit my previous statement.  pin is ok being a string, however ApparentPower and AnalogueRead should be float.  Is it possible to change them?

Comment: They should be written with the correct data type into InfluxDB. See the line protocol docs for details: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#examples

Comment: OK, i think i know where i went wrong in the first place.  The json i sent to the node-red is written as follows {"measurement": "machine01", "timestamp": 1613579020963916544, "fields": {"ApparentPower": "46.76", "AnalogueRead": 0.20}}.  I need to change it to remove the quotes around the fields like so {"ApparentPower": 46.76, "AnalogueRead": 0.20}.

Comment: Can i change the existing data types or will I need to remove the measurement?

Comment: You can write to a different field name, or DROP MEASUREMENT machine01. Or if you have sharding, wait until writes go to the next shard.

Comment: I think writing to a different field name is better, thanks for the options.

Comment: added extra columns and  removing the quotes around the fields like so {"floatApparentPower": 46.76, "floatAnalogueRead": 0.20} work.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, the "ApparentPower" field is written to InfluxDB as a string.

You can verify this using: `SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "machine01"`

A field must be written as integer or float in order to be compared with `<`

**Changing the data type**:

You cannot change the data type of an existing measurement field, but you can:

- write to a different field name,
- remove the measurement using `DROP MEASUREMENT machine01`,
- if you have sharding enabled, wait until writes go to the next shard.